# Angular application Deploy on BlueMix - Route not found eror

Tags: node.js, angular, ibm-cloud

I have tried this demo angular app - **http://md-angular2.creative-tim.com/#/dashboard**

- And deployed it on to IBM bluemix. using the cloudfoundry tools - The app has been deployed to the IBM bluemix server succesfully.

This Application works fine on the localhost, but fails on IBM Bluemix.
On launching the app , it returns a route error as mentioned below.

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('tiedashboard-cupolated-prestissimo.mybluemix.net') does not exist.
```

Demo app installed on IBM bluemix - URL :-
[https://tiedashboard-cupolated-prestissimo.mybluemix.net/](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-pro-angular2)

Angular 2 Demo Application from

**http://md-angular2.creative-tim.com/#/dashboard**

https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-pro-angular2

The manifest file I have used is as given below:-

applications:

name: TieDashboard
random-route: true
memory: 256M

I have used cloud foundry to tools to deploy
cf push
This push has been successfully deployed onto the Bluemix cloud

However despite all this, the app returns with a route not found error.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

[image]

**Click Link to full CloudFoundry Log file ...**
[Full Log File from cf](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/imboss/log.txt)

cf Log File ouput given below

```
   2017-07-18T10:55:38.81+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T11:13:30.12+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T11:13:41.43+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
   2017-07-18T11:13:55.38+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
   2017-07-18T11:13:55.40+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
   2017-07-18T11:13:55.40+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  UI External: http://10.254.0.226:3001
   2017-07-18T11:14:00.66+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
   2017-07-18T11:14:00.66+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] 
   2017-07-18T11:14:00.66+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] Error: watch vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/path-array/node_modules/array-index/node_modules/es6-symbol/node_modules/es5-ext/array/_is-extensible.js ENOSPC
   2017-07-18T11:14:00.66+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
   2017-07-18T11:14:00.66+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
   2017-07-18T11:14:00.66+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
   2017-07-18T11:14:05.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] 9:14:05 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
   2017-07-18T11:14:52.94+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-07-18T11:31:21.02+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T11:32:16.50+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
   2017-07-18T11:32:18.02+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Access URLs:
   2017-07-18T11:32:18.08+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
   2017-07-18T11:32:18.08+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  UI External: http://10.254.0.2:3001
   [31m2017-07-18T11:32:43.76+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Exit status 4[0m
   2017-07-18T11:32:54.82+0200 [API/6] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-07-18T11:32:54.85+0200 [API/6] OUT App instance exited with guid b7ddaa22-e546-4f01-99a1-84987cb59f27 payload: {"instance"=>"69098992-f256-4baf-67f6-53e4", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Instance never healthy after 1m0s: healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.2:8080: getsockopt: connection refused\nExit status 4\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* cancelled\n* process did not exit", "crash_count"=>20, "crash_timestamp"=>1500370374784736073, "version"=>"b361963b-8f0f-4fcb-91e3-6b13e055ec6a"}
   2017-07-18T11:49:04.27+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-07-18T11:49:06.81+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T11:49:14.10+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-07-18T11:49:15.38+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > material-dashboard-angular2@1.2.0 start /home/vcap/app
   2017-07-18T11:49:15.38+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.17+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.17+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] ** browser-sync config **
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.19+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] { injectChanges: false,
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.19+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.19+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.19+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Access URLs:
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  ------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     External: http://10.254.1.54:3000
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  ------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  UI External: http://10.254.1.54:3001
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  ------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.53+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.58+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Watching files...
   2017-07-18T11:49:23.70+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
   2017-07-18T11:49:27.61+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] Killed
   2017-07-18T11:49:27.63+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] tsc -w exited with code 137
   [31m2017-07-18T11:50:16.25+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.1.54:8080: getsockopt: connection refused[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T11:50:16.25+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Exit status 4[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T11:50:16.25+0200 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.[0m
   2017-07-18T11:50:16.25+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-07-18T11:50:27.27+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-07-18T11:50:27.30+0200 [API/2] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-07-18T11:50:27.32+0200 [API/2] OUT App instance exited with guid b7ddaa22-e546-4f01-99a1-84987cb59f27 payload: {"instance"=>"2d1a4a7d-5fcc-4496-530f-32e2", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Instance never healthy after 1m0s: healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.1.54:8080: getsockopt: connection refused\nExit status 4\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* cancelled\n* process did not exit", "crash_count"=>21, "crash_timestamp"=>1500371427264759786, "version"=>"b361963b-8f0f-4fcb-91e3-6b13e055ec6a"}
   2017-07-18T11:50:29.08+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
   2017-07-18T12:06:58.70+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-07-18T12:07:01.45+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T12:07:05.94+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-07-18T12:07:07.10+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > material-dashboard-angular2@1.2.0 start /home/vcap/app
   2017-07-18T12:07:07.10+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
   2017-07-18T12:07:15.96+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
   2017-07-18T12:07:15.96+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] ** browser-sync config **
   2017-07-18T12:07:15.96+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] { injectChanges: false,
   2017-07-18T12:07:15.96+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
   2017-07-18T12:07:15.96+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
   2017-07-18T12:07:15.96+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.68+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Access URLs:
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.71+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.71+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.71+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     External: http://10.254.0.114:3000
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.71+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.73+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.73+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  UI External: http://10.254.0.114:3001
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.73+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.73+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
   2017-07-18T12:07:16.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Watching files...
   2017-07-18T12:07:17.02+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
   2017-07-18T12:07:20.88+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] Killed
   2017-07-18T12:07:20.90+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] tsc -w exited with code 137
   [31m2017-07-18T12:08:08.12+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.114:8080: getsockopt: connection refused[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:08:08.12+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Exit status 4[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:08:08.12+0200 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.[0m
   2017-07-18T12:08:08.12+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-07-18T12:08:19.13+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-07-18T12:08:19.17+0200 [API/10] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-07-18T12:08:19.19+0200 [API/10] OUT App instance exited with guid b7ddaa22-e546-4f01-99a1-84987cb59f27 payload: {"instance"=>"49efcc33-a26f-425b-4705-5849", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Instance never healthy after 1m0s: healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.114:8080: getsockopt: connection refused\nExit status 4\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* cancelled\n* process did not exit", "crash_count"=>22, "crash_timestamp"=>1500372499130263317, "version"=>"b361963b-8f0f-4fcb-91e3-6b13e055ec6a"}
   2017-07-18T12:08:21.20+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
   2017-07-18T12:24:53.03+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-07-18T12:24:56.35+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T12:25:06.06+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-07-18T12:25:09.29+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > material-dashboard-angular2@1.2.0 start /home/vcap/app
   2017-07-18T12:25:09.29+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
   2017-07-18T12:25:26.79+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
   2017-07-18T12:25:26.80+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] ** browser-sync config **
   2017-07-18T12:25:26.81+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] { injectChanges: false,
   2017-07-18T12:25:26.81+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
   2017-07-18T12:25:26.81+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
   2017-07-18T12:25:26.81+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.42+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Access URLs:
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.42+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.46+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.46+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     External: http://10.254.0.178:3000
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.46+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.46+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.46+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  UI External: http://10.254.0.178:3001
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.46+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.46+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.51+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Watching files...
   2017-07-18T12:25:27.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
   2017-07-18T12:25:36.08+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] Killed
   2017-07-18T12:25:36.20+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] tsc -w exited with code 137
   [31m2017-07-18T12:26:09.74+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.178:8080: getsockopt: connection refused[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:26:09.74+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Exit status 4[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:26:09.74+0200 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.[0m
   2017-07-18T12:26:09.76+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-07-18T12:26:20.76+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-07-18T12:26:20.79+0200 [API/10] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-07-18T12:26:20.82+0200 [API/10] OUT App instance exited with guid b7ddaa22-e546-4f01-99a1-84987cb59f27 payload: {"instance"=>"8fc91c66-90b2-464e-77d0-3f86", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Instance never healthy after 1m0s: healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.178:8080: getsockopt: connection refused\nExit status 4\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* cancelled\n* process did not exit", "crash_count"=>23, "crash_timestamp"=>1500373580759283770, "version"=>"b361963b-8f0f-4fcb-91e3-6b13e055ec6a"}
   2017-07-18T12:26:22.88+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
   2017-07-18T12:33:41.02+0200 [API/2] OUT Updated app with guid b7ddaa22-e546-4f01-99a1-84987cb59f27 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
   2017-07-18T12:33:44.15+0200 [API/4] OUT Updated app with guid b7ddaa22-e546-4f01-99a1-84987cb59f27 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
   2017-07-18T12:33:44.91+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-07-18T12:33:48.17+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T12:33:55.71+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-07-18T12:33:57.68+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > material-dashboard-angular2@1.2.0 start /home/vcap/app
   2017-07-18T12:33:57.68+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
   2017-07-18T12:34:10.69+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
   2017-07-18T12:34:10.69+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] ** browser-sync config **
   2017-07-18T12:34:10.69+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] { injectChanges: false,
   2017-07-18T12:34:10.69+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
   2017-07-18T12:34:10.69+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
   2017-07-18T12:34:10.69+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.34+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Access URLs:
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.34+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  ------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.34+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.35+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     External: http://10.254.0.98:3000
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.37+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  ------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.37+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.37+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  UI External: http://10.254.0.98:3001
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.37+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  ------------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.37+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.45+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Watching files...
   2017-07-18T12:34:11.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
   2017-07-18T12:34:18.70+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] Killed
   2017-07-18T12:34:18.72+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] tsc -w exited with code 137
   [31m2017-07-18T12:34:56.76+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.98:8080: getsockopt: connection refused[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:34:56.76+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Exit status 4[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:34:56.76+0200 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.[0m
   2017-07-18T12:34:56.82+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-07-18T12:35:08.01+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-07-18T12:35:08.06+0200 [API/2] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-07-18T12:35:08.08+0200 [API/2] OUT App instance exited with guid b7ddaa22-e546-4f01-99a1-84987cb59f27 payload: {"instance"=>"261ffc93-eef0-4760-6d1d-9eb8", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Instance never healthy after 1m0s: healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.98:8080: getsockopt: connection refused\nExit status 4\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* cancelled\n* process did not exit", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1500374107783471887, "version"=>"d9f5b01b-e7f9-40fd-a601-8f10f010ad26"}
   2017-07-18T12:35:08.36+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-07-18T12:35:10.78+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
   2017-07-18T12:35:11.33+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-07-18T12:35:17.27+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-07-18T12:35:18.36+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > material-dashboard-angular2@1.2.0 start /home/vcap/app
   2017-07-18T12:35:18.36+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
   2017-07-18T12:35:25.58+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
   2017-07-18T12:35:25.60+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] ** browser-sync config **
   2017-07-18T12:35:25.61+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] { injectChanges: false,
   2017-07-18T12:35:25.61+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
   2017-07-18T12:35:25.61+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
   2017-07-18T12:35:25.61+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.04+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Access URLs:
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.04+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -----------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]     External: http://10.254.0.2:3000
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -----------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  UI External: http://10.254.0.2:3001
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1]  -----------------------------------
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.05+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.09+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Watching files...
   2017-07-18T12:35:26.22+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [1] [BS] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
   2017-07-18T12:35:29.84+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] Killed
   2017-07-18T12:35:29.84+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [0] tsc -w exited with code 137
   [31m2017-07-18T12:36:17.95+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.2:8080: getsockopt: connection refused[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:36:17.95+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Exit status 4[0m
   [31m2017-07-18T12:36:17.95+0200 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.[0m
   2017-07-18T12:36:17.96+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-07-18T12:36:29.01+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-07-18T12:36:29.10+0200 [API/0] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
```

**Error Log File from Bluemix Dashboard**

```
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 03:02:43.770 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 03:38:08.121 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.114:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 03:38:08.121 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 03:38:08.121 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 03:56:09.748 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 03:56:09.748 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.178:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 03:56:09.748 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.98:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:04:56.767 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:04:56.767 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:04:56.767 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:06:17.950 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:06:17.950 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.2:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:06:17.950 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:07:45.992 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.82:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:07:45.992 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:07:45.992 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:10:11.519 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.0.162:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:10:11.519 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:10:11.520 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:13:19.172 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:13:19.172 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.2.10:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:13:19.172 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.2.50:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:17:11.753 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:17:11.753 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:17:11.753 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:23:10.759 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:23:10.759 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.1.86:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:23:10.759 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.1.230:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:33:00.889 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:33:00.889 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:33:00.889 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:44:12.912 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:44:12.912 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.1.118:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:44:12.912 PM
HEALTH/0Exit status 4Jul 18, 2017 04:45:38.392 PM
CELL/0Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.Jul 18, 2017 04:45:38.392 PM
HEALTH/0healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.2.58:8080: getsockopt: connection refusedJul 18, 2017 04:45:38.392 PM
```

I have updated the package.json file
to include the below lines

> "start": "concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" ",  "lite":
> "lite-server",
> "tsc": "tsc",
> "tsc:w": "tsc -w"

And the Errors are now as

```
  2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! node v6.10.2
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! material-dashboard-angular2@1.2.0 start: `concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! 
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Failed at the material-dashboard-angular2@1.2.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the material-dashboard-angular2 package,
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     npm bugs material-dashboard-angular2
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls material-dashboard-angular2
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.32+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.33+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   2017-07-25T10:40:43.33+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: How did you deploy it? How does the manifest look like? Which command options did you use?

Comment: applications:
 - name: TieDashboard
   random-route: true
   memory: 256M

Comment: `cf push` for the app returned no error at all? What was the route that is shown by Bluemix? In the Bluemix browser UI is a link to the app and its current status.

Comment: cf push - was perfect - the app was uploaded into the bluemix dashboard.  State was green on the dashboard and running.

Comment: Added a screenshot of bluemix control panel

Comment: Added partial Log File. For Full log file check this link - https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/imboss/log.txt

Comment: Added the Error Log File from the bluemix Dashboard.

Comment: Updated the Package.json  with this line -                                                 "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ", This keeps the server running properly now.  However the route error still persists

Comment: Health Check never passed - Timeout Error in Logs.

Comment: cf apps require to listen on PORT (an environment variable). Does your app do it?

Comment: No, I havent configured any PORT variable.

Comment: I have added port = 3000  to manifest.yml - and pushed the changes. But it ends up with error - healthcheck failed - failure to connect to tcp 10.****:8080 port connect refused.

Comment: cf tells your app which port to use. You need to grab it from PORT in your code. Google it.

Comment: Well, I turned it off - the health-check-type to none.

Comment: Now I am getting a 502  error - Gateway not found rubbish. Progress I suppose.